# Is it possible to choose the size of the pdf when exporting in Libreoffice (Draw)?

Tags: pdf, export, draw, libreoffice

The question says everything. The solution I found so far is to redefine the size of the page to the size of my drawing, but this process is not as easy as it was supposed to be (you need to keep changing values and checking if it fits while it should just give a way to select what you want).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Initial View, under Magnification choose Fit in Window

https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Export_as_PDF#Fit_in_window